# Advice for developing on a WP7 device without a phone plan

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to start developing Win Phone 7 apps before it's too late. I'm not sure my motivation is high enough to do so without a physical device to play with, but I don't want to switch to T-Mobile or AT&T (US) to get a device.

I'm quite happy paying full retail price - but get left with a lot of questions.

- Will the device be fully functional without an active phone plan?
- Is it important to test on a device that has a physical keyboard
- Where is the best place to buy a retail price phone
- Will I still get system updates through wi-fi without an active phone plan - or can I just borrow a friend's AT&T SIM card when I know an update is available
- Are unlocked phones available - or are they still tied to the carrier

etc.

Preferably I'd like to be able to use the phone when in UK (less frequently than once a year)

Comment: I'm hoping Microsoft does a developer phone program for this exact reason, similar to the Google developer phone program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes - subject to not having network connectivity. You can still wifi for data.
- Not critical, you can emulate this with PAUSE in the emulator.
- Depends on your area.
- Updates through Zune when hooked up to your PC.
- I'm not aware of any carrier lock ins like iPhone.

Comment: thanks mick. i just went to AT&T store - and they told me that not only could they NOT even sell me a phone without me being a customer, but the 'no commitment' price did not give me an unlocked phone - but would be locked to AT&T. hmm. does he know what he's talking about ?

Comment: It seems to depend on the store here in Aus... they make more profit if they sell contracts, and since phones are in limited supply, some are willing to put their profits before their customers needs. I suppose they have that right. The lock in I haven't looked into extensively.. perhaps it's there... I've just not heard anything about it if so.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, I believe the Microsoft Stores sell unlocked Lumia 800s; you can probably grab them online as well?